How do I actually download the ubuntu desktop iso?
Selecting the "Download ubuntu desktop" navigates me to the previous page.  No errors or anything.
I simply can't start the ubuntu desktop download.
Is there another location to download the iso?
Thanks.

You can download the noble-desktop-amd64.iso file directly by using this link: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/noble-desktop-amd64.iso.

We don't know what page you are using.

You've not actually said what release etc. you want, as some releases have choices of ISO (each using a different installer) as all you mention is Ubuntu Desktop (of which there are many releases; some with multiple ISO chocies).   Personally I go to https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ and navigate to what I want from there

Does this answer your question? How to download Ubuntu without installing?

WTF, really?  Don't know what page or release?  Go to the Ubuntu Website, try to download Ubuntu Desktop.  I'm at work and needed an iso for development and testing.   Don't really have the time traverse the site for a hidden solution.  I mean, point click select an iso and download.  The LTS download link on the same page works as I would expect.  Why not the Desktop version?  Doesn't matter any more honestly.

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

The official site can be found here:
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
Alternatively, here is a list of mirrors:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors
